# Add-Migration MyModel gives empty Up() Down() methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created model with some fields (including `public int Id {get; set; }`). I try to add the first migration: `Add-Migration MyModel`, after which a file with empty Up() and Down() methods is created.

Is it possible that the problem is that the db context file is empty?

ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace TimeTracker.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }
```

I already tried solutions from other questions.
I tried `Add-Migration InitialCreate`, then `Update-Database`, remove all migrations and database, create new project. It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: what is IdentityDbContext? It is your class or some library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the newly created  Model in the ApplicationDbContext Class.

```
public DbSet<ModelName> ModelPropertyName { get; set; }
```

Comment: @lleviy check whether you have missed adding it in the context class ?

Comment: Do I need to specify all properties of the model? The documentation says that I can write simply `public DbSet<ModelName> ModelName{ get; set; }` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio
Unfortunately, `Add-Migration InitialCreate` does not work in this case. I get "Build failed".

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. The properties must be mentioned in the model and not in the context. What build errors you are getting ?

Answer (score 1):

Your DB context does not know that you want your entity to be mapped to database. You must add some DbSet property before.

```
public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
```

If Your entity would have some relationship with foreign key there is no need to add both class properties. EF Core will see this relationship if you specify navigation property in your entity class or/and customize it in `OnModelCreating` method with Fluent API

You can also cusomize your migration with attributes or using Fluent API your EFContext's method OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder):

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Property(b => b.Url)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/)